# Collections.forEach: How to add up values?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have `List<Transaction>` where `Transaction` has `amount` as `BigDecimal`.

I want to add up all the `amount` in this list. I do something as

```
BigDecimal spent = new BigDecimal("0.0");
transactions.forEach(t -> spent.add(t.getAmount()));
System.out.println(spent);
```

When I run this, `spent` turns out to be `0.0`

Also, syntactically `transactions.forEach(t -> spent = spent.add(t.getAmount()));` throws compilation errors.

I am trying to learn doing it without using `for each` loop

Ideas?

Comment: BigDecimal is immutable..

Comment: I find it strange that the first version works at all, since `BigDecimal`'s `.add()` returns a `BigDecimal` which is not `void`...

Answer (score 3):

After reading up on [Adding up BigDecimals using Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635945/adding-up-bigdecimals-using-streams) , I found out that the following is what I needed

```
final Function<Transaction, BigDecimal> transactionAmountMapper = Transaction::getAmount;
final BigDecimal result = entry.getValue().stream().map(transactionAmountMapper).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Comment: OK well, that's one solution; also, you can't reaffect "out of scope" variables in a lambda: they need to be effectively final. Note that there are adders for int, long and double, just not Big*.

Comment: Not sure if I completely followed you @fge

Answer (score 1):

Try streams instead of foreach

```
    List<BigDecimal> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(new BigDecimal(10));
    list.add(new BigDecimal(10));
    list.add(new BigDecimal(10));
    BigDecimal total = list.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);

    System.out.println(total);
```