# Stream not working in for loop

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

```
BigDecimal getInterest(List<Investment> investments) {
        BigDecimal interest = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        for (Investment i: investments) {
            i.getTransactions().stream()
                    .map(Transaction::getAmount)
                    .forEach(interest::add);
        }
        return interest;
    }
```

The problem with this method is that it always returns zero. It looks like  `.forEach()` is not consuming it's argument. However if I write it the way below, everything is working fine. Anyone got idea why the first method is not working?

```
BigDecimal getInterest(List<Investment> investments) {
        BigDecimal interest = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        for (Investment i: investments) {
            interestPaid = interest.add(i.getTransactions().stream()
                    .map(Transaction::getAmount)
                    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add));
        }
        return interest;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe because BigDecimal is immutable, so it returns a new instance when calling add instead of updating the original one?

Comment: @Eran: It's a `BigDecimal`, which is the problem here.

Comment: @fabian I missed that, thanks. Actually it's BigDecimal, but same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding up BigDecimals using Streams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635945/adding-up-bigdecimals-using-streams)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BigDecimal` is immutable, so your `forEach` is calling `add`, but not doing anything with the result. `reduce` is the right stream operator in this case.

If you see [Adding up BigDecimals using Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635945/adding-up-bigdecimals-using-streams). You should use `.reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)`, which would make your loop body:

```
interest = i.getTransactions().stream()
                .map(Transaction::getAmount)
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `BigDecimal` is immutable, calling `add` for it won't change the value. It instead returns a new `BigDecimal`. `forEach` simply ignores any values returned.

`interest` will always keep it's initial value of `BigDecimal.ZERO`.

In contrast to that `reduce` combines the elements using a given `BinaryOperator`. `BigDecimal::add` is actually a short form for `(a, b) -> a.add(b)` and this operator will be applied to combine all stream elements.

Answer (score 1):

As the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39365539/2711488) explains,  `BigDecimal.add` does not modify the instance, but returns a new value and your first variant is not using the result. As an addendum, the same would happen if you don’t use the result of `reduce` in you second variant, but there, you not only pass the result to an invocation of `add` on the previous value, you also care to assign the result of that subsequent `add` to your local variable.

But it’s worth noting that your mixture of loop and stream operation in inconsistent. You can express the entire operation as a single Stream operation:

```
BigDecimal getInterest(List<Investment> investments) {
    return investments.stream()
        .flatMap(i -> i.getTransactions().stream())
        .map(Transaction::getAmount)
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
```