# Is there a mutable reduction operation(Collector) for Stream<BigDecimal>?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

AFAIK the only way to sum a stream of `BigDecimal` is:

```
BigDecimal result = stream.reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

The problem here is that every call to `BigDecimal::add` will create a new `BigDecimal` as opposed to changing a mutable type.

Is there a mutable reduction operation aka `Collector` for `Stream<BigDecimal>`?

Comment: see this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635945/adding-up-bigdecimals-using-streams

Comment: unless one exists already you'd need something analogous to a `StringBuilder` (but for `BigDecimal`), since `BigDecimal` is immutable.

Comment: “The problem here is …”—did you actually verify that there is such a problem, i.e. did a profiling tool tell you that? Modern JVMs are usually good at dealing with temporary objects created in a hot loop. You should only act when necessary, especially as a solution would require re-implementing parts of that existing class.

Comment: @Holger good point and no I didn't do any profiling, I was just surprised when I realized that there is no `Collector` for this purpose given that the purpose of `Collector` was to deal with this kind of situation. I was expecting the existence of `MutableBigInteger` or something analogous but maybe the JVM just optimizes the "problem" away.

Comment: Well, `Collector`s can deal with mutable types, if they exist, but a public mutable `BigDecimal` companion never existed and the future development will clearly go towards more JVM improvements (for the benefit of *all* value types) rather than adding a mutable helper class for every immutable class.

Comment: @Holger if you rewrite your comments as an answer I will make it the accepted one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is no public mutable `BigDecimal` companion class, so there is no `Collector` using it. But you should not worry about the performance implication of the instance creation unless a profiling tool tells you that there is a problem.

Modern JVMs like HotSpot are usually good at dealing with temporary objects created in a hot loop. Even if they are not able to elide the allocation, the allocation costs are not so big. This is different to, e.g. `String::concat` where the instance creation costs do not only include the allocation, but copying the entire contents of the previously created `String` instances, yielding a quadratic time complexity of such reduction (unless the optimizer manages to rewrite such code). The same would apply to attempts to produce a `Collection` via pure (immutable) reduction.

This might be contradicting to the existence of primitive type specializations like `IntStream`, `LongStream` and `DoubleStream`, but that’s a trade-off. Generally, the preference of the JRE developers is towards improving the JVM performance (for the benefit of *all* value types) rather than adding a mutable helper class for every immutable class. There might be a continuity of special support for primitive types until the arrival of full value type support, but don’t expect the addition of new public mutable companion classes for immutable types (unless we’re talking about construction costs like in the `String` example).

Answer (score 5):

BigDecimal: "Immutable, arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers."

Since its immutable there is no method to manipulate them without creating new objects. Any method that can do that would break guarantees of the class (like BigDecimal.ZERO being 0)

Comment: Understood. But why is there no mutable accumulation version of `BigInteger` to create a `Collector`? I.e. why is there no `MutableBigInteger`?

Comment: Going by this comment from the Java implementers: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=813487c6e93a54f6f2f437bc69cd?bug_id=4379405 - They don't think such a class is required and the immutable implementation is enough when paired with JVM optimizations.