# Summing BigDecimal with Collectors

Tags: java, lambda, collectors

I want to sum the `cost` property of items in a `List`.
I have written a stream to collect these items and perform the sum, using `groupingBy()`, as illustrated below.

```
groupingBy(
    ...,
    ...,
    Collectors.summingDouble(e->e.cost.doubleValue())
)
```

However, the `cost` field is a `BigDecimal`. In the code above, I am converting it to `double`, which makes me cringe. Is there a "drop-in" method I can write to that effect ? That would be an equivalent of `summingBigDecimal()`, which does not exist.

This is not a duplicate of [Adding up BigDecimals using Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635945/adding-up-bigdecimals-using-streams) as the answers are not applicable inside a groupingBy. Agreed with Anthony Garcia.

Comment: Maybe this works? `Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)`

Comment: No it does not work. Thanks for offering.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635945/adding-up-bigdecimals-using-streams, as the answers are not applicable inside a `groupingBy`. The correct answer is to do `groupingBy(..., ..., Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, YourObjClass::cost, BigDecimal::add))`.