# Bad return type in lambda expression: BigDecimal cannot be converted to long

Tags: java, java-stream, bigdecimal, speedment

I was trying to write a query in java stream, through speedment.
When I try to `sum (l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount))` in select, I get this error:

> Bad return type in lambda expression: **BigDecimal cannot be converted to long. Operator '-' cannot be applied to 'int', 'java.math.BigDecimal'**.

My code is this:

```
JoinComponent joinComponent = app.getOrThrow(JoinComponent.class);
Join<Tuple6<Customer, Orders, Lineitem, Supplier, Nation, Region>> join = joinComponent
        .from(CustomerManager.IDENTIFIER)
        .innerJoinOn(Orders.O_CUSTKEY).equal(Customer.C_CUSTKEY)
        .where(Orders.O_ORDERDATE.greaterOrEqual(sqlDate))
        .where(Orders.O_ORDERDATE.lessThan(sqlDate2))
        .innerJoinOn(Lineitem.L_ORDERKEY).equal(Orders.O_ORDERDATE)
        .innerJoinOn(Supplier.S_SUPPKEY ).equal(Customer.C_NATIONKEY)
        .innerJoinOn(Nation.N_NATIONKEY).equal(Supplier.S_NATIONKEY)
        .innerJoinOn(Region.R_REGIONKEY).equal(Nation.N_REGIONKEY)
        .where(Region.R_NAME.equal("ASIA"))
        .build(Tuples::of);

Comparator<Tuple1<String>> comparator = Comparator
        .comparing((Function<Tuple1<String>, String>) Tuple1::get0)
        .thenComparing(Tuple1::get0);

Map<Tuple1<String>, LongSummaryStatistics> grouped = join.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(t -> Tuples.of(t.get4().getNName()),
                () -> new TreeMap<>(comparator),
                summarizingLong(t->t.get2().getLDiscount()*(1-t.get2().getLDiscount()))
        ));
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I'd guess `t.get2().getLDiscount()*(1-t.get2().getLDiscount())` is the problem and that `getLDiscount()` returns a `BigDecimal`. You can't say `1 - BigDecimal`, and you can't do `BigDecimal * BigDecimal`. But that's just an assumption, because you haven't posted `getLDiscount()`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch,  public BigDecimal getLDiscount() {
        return lDiscount;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, ... are not working with `BigDecimal`s. You have to use `.add()`, `.subtract()`, `.multiply()`, `.divide()`, ... methods for calculations.

If it is possible, you can use [`BigDecimal.longValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#longValue--) or [`BigDecimal.longValueExact()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#longValueExact--) to convert the `BigDecimal`s to long values to use them in your calculation:

```
Map<Tuple1<String>, LongSummaryStatistics> grouped = join.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Tuples::of,
                () -> new TreeMap<>(comparator),
                Collectors.summarizingLong(t -> t.get2().getLDiscount().longValue() *
                        (1 - t.get2().getLDiscount().longValue()))
        ));
```

Alternatively you can du the whole calculation with `BigDecimal` and convert the value to long at the end:

```
Map<Tuple1<String>, LongSummaryStatistics> grouped = join.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Tuples::of,
                () -> new TreeMap<>(comparator),
                Collectors.summarizingLong(t -> t.get2().getLDiscount()
                        .multiply(BigDecimal.ONE
                        .subtract(t.get2().getLDiscount())).longValue())
        ));
```

If both solutions do not work for you you have to write an own collection for `BigDecimalSummaryStatistics` or just calculate the values you need directly. You can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22635945/9662601) for summarizing `BigDecimal` values using Java Stream.