# Creating an object binding of a list of BigDecimals to get a total

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create a binding of a list of `LineItem`'s amounts with the following line:

```
ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<BigDecimal> total = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>();

total.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> items.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.summingDouble(LineItem::getTotal)),
                        items));
```

Obviously, the `Collectors.summingDouble` won't work as it's a `BigDecimal`. Is there any way to do this with a BigDecimal?

**LineItem.java**

```
public class LineItem
{
        private final SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal> amount;
        
        public LineItem()
        {
            this.amount = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        }
        
        public BigDecimal getTotal()
        {
            return this.amount.get();
        }
        
}
```

Ideally, changes to the properties will reflect in the total property...

Comment: Voted to reopen. This question is about creating a JavaFX binding, that is not what the [previously linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635945/adding-up-bigdecimals-using-streams) documented.

Comment: Is the list of `LineItem` an [ObservableLIst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) ?

Comment: @Abra yes it is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few changes to make to make this work:

1. You need to define a "property accessor" method in your `LineItem` class, to access the actual `ObjectProperty<BigDecimal>` (not just the `BigDecimal` it wraps). This allows the list to send notifications if the individual amounts change.
2. You need to create your `ObservableList` with an ["extractor"](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.base/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList(javafx.util.Callback)), so it can send update notifications to your binding, if the individual amount properties change
3. Fix the function in the binding to sum the `BigDecimal` instances, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635945/adding-up-bigdecimals-using-streams)

This looks like:

```
public class LineItem {
    private final SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal> amount;
    
    public LineItem()
    {
        this.amount = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    }
    
    public final BigDecimal getTotal()
    {
        return this.amount.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> totalProperty() {
        return amount ;
    }

    public final void setTotal(BigDecimal total) {
        totalProperty().set(total);
    }
    
}
```

then

```
ObservableList<LineItem> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    item -> new Observable[] {item.totalProperty()}
);
```

and

```
total.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> items.stream()
         .map(LineItem::getTotal)
         .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add),
     items));
```

Comment: The "extractor" was the missing piece. thanks.