# Effectively Final Variable not working in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a methode that use an effectively final variable total intialised with 0, i'm suposed to have the sum of products price but i'm always getting 0, can someone tell me what i'm missing

```
    public BigDecimal getTotalAmount() {
        BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        products.forEach(product -> total.add(product.getPrice()));
        return total;
    }
```

Comment: BigDecimal is *immutable* type. When you do `total.add(product.getPrice())` it doesn't *modify* object held by `total`, but produces new BigDecimal object which you discard.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `BigDecimal.add` returns a new BigDecimal and doesn't mutate the original variable. Try using `reduce` in place of `forEach`

Comment: Related: [Adding up BigDecimals using Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22635945)

Comment: thanks that's answering my question